# Replace a value in a column by vlookup another dataframe only if the value exists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, matching

I want to overwrite my `df1.Name` values based on a mapping table in `(df2.Name1, df2.Name2)`. However, not all values in `df1.Name` exist in `df2.Name1`

#### df1:

```
Name
Alex
Maria 
Marias
Pandas
Coala
```

#### df2:

```
Name1   Name2
Alex    Alexs
Marias  Maria
Coala   Coalas
```

#### Expected Result:

```
Name
Alexs
Maria
Maria
Pandas
Coalas
```

I have tried several solutions online such as using the Map function. By turning `df2` in a Dictionary I am using `df1.Name = df1.Name.map(Dictionary)`, but this will result in `nan` for all values not in `df2` as per below.

```
Name
Alexs
Maria
Maria
NAN
Coalas
```

I am not sure how to use an IF statement to replace only the ones that do exist in df2 and keep the rest as per df1.
I also tried to create a function with `if` statements, but was big time failure.

How I could approach this problem?

Comment: The expected result is an updated df1.Name dataframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `replace`

```
df1.Name.replace(df2.set_index('Name1').Name2.to_dict())
Out[437]: 
0     Alexs
1     Maria
2     Maria
3    Pandas
4    Coalas
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Python `dict.get()` allows a default parameter.  So if you build a translation dict, then if the lookup is not found, it is easy to just returned the original value like:

#### Code:

```
translate = {x: y for x, y in df2[['Name1', 'Name2']].values}
new_names = [translate.get(x, x) for x in df1['Name']]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alex', 'Maria', 'Marias', 'Pandas', 'Coala']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': ['Alex', 'Marias', 'Coala'],
                    'Name2': ['Alexs', 'Maria', 'Coalas']})

print(df1)
print(df2)

translate = {x: y for x, y in df2[['Name1', 'Name2']].values}
print([translate.get(x, x) for x in df1['Name']])
```

#### Test Results:

```
     Name
0    Alex
1   Maria
2  Marias
3  Pandas
4   Coala

    Name1   Name2
0    Alex   Alexs
1  Marias   Maria
2   Coala  Coalas

['Alexs', 'Maria', 'Maria', 'Pandas', 'Coalas']
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but how can I get this back as a dataframe as I would like the df1.Name to keep the updated names (when available)

Comment: `df1.Name = new_names`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alex', 'Maria', 'Marias', 'Pandas', 'Coala']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': ['Alex', 'Marias', 'Coala'],
                    'Name2': ['Alexs', 'Maria', 'Coalas']})

# Create the dictionary from df2
d = {"Name": {k:v for k, v in zip(df2["Name1"], df2["Name2"])}}
# Suggestion from Wen to create the dictionary
# d = {"Name": df2.set_index('Name1').Name2.to_dict()}     

df1.replace(d)   # Use df1.replace(d, inplace=True) if you want this in place

    Name
0   Alexs
1   Maria
2   Maria
3   Pandas
4   Coalas
```

[`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) can take a dictionary, where you can specify the column to do replace, `"Name"` here, and the corresponding mapping that you want to replace in this particular column.

```
{"Name": {old_1: new_1, old_2: new_2...}}
```

-> replace values in `"Name"` column such that `old_1` will be replaced with `new_1`. `old_2` will be replaced by `new_2` and so on.

Thanks for the setup from Stephen Rauch. Thanks for Wen for offering a clean way to create dictionary.

Comment: Check my , you do not need to create the dict via loop :- ）

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a Pandas solution with `map` and `combine_first`:

```
df1['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name1')['Name2']).combine_first(df1['Name'])
```

Output:

```
0     Alexs
1     Maria
2     Maria
3    Pandas
4    Coalas
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: this results the below error for me:  InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Ah.. you just have duplicate 'Name1' in your df2?

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `merge`:

```
In [27]: df1['Name'] = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'Name1':'Name'}), how='left') \
                          .ffill(axis=1)['Name2']

In [28]: df1
Out[28]:
     Name
0   Alexs
1   Maria
2   Maria
3  Pandas
4  Coalas
```