# How pick data from one pandas dataframe and add it to the other pandas dataframe based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have two data frames - DF1 and DF2. Both have an "ID" column.

How do I copy a value from a different column in DF1 based on the "ID" value in a row to a corresponding row in DF2 which has the same "ID"?

To put it simply, I think I am trying to replicate the VLOOKUP functionality from Microsoft Excel in Python Pandas.

Comment: I believe several working methods can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269844/replace-a-value-in-a-column-by-vlookup-another-dataframe-only-if-the-value-exist

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.join()` can act similar with the `VLOOKUP`. It joins a column at the first `dataframe` with the index of the second `dataframe`.

**test code :**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['B', 'C', 'D'],
                    'Column': [1, 2, 3]})

df1.join(df2.set_index('ID')['Column'], on='ID')
```

**test result :**

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('ID')['Column'], on='ID')
Out[2]: 
  ID  Column
0  A     NaN
1  B     1.0
2  C     2.0
3  D     3.0
4  E     NaN
```